# make ajax call in the background while rendering reactjs component without freezing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is an ajax call made in componentDidMount supposed to freeze the page for a couple of seconds? I can't click or select anything until the ajax call completes, it's only retrieving about 3MB of data. I think the entire page finishes rendering but for some reason it just freezes while the date is being retrieved.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: no that shouldn't happen, can't help you any further without seeing the code :/

Comment: figured it out, it's cuz i'm doing a lot of data processing right with the data right after retrieving it so it freezes the page

Comment: you should put the data processing logic in the backend. you should just receive data and display it in your UI. Its usually not a good idea to do a lot of processing in UI

Comment: what is the difference between processing it in the front end vs the backend? doesn't the frontend still have to wait until the data is returned from backend?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) for such purpose. It will run in a separate thread, so it won't freeze your UI behavior.

But notice:

> You can run whatever code you like inside the worker thread, with some
>   exceptions. For example, you can't directly manipulate the DOM from
>   inside a worker, or use some default methods and properties of the
>   [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object. But you can use a large number of items available under
>   window, including WebSockets, and data storage mechanisms like
>   IndexedDB and the Firefox OS-only Data Store API. See [Functions and
>   classes available to workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers) for more details.